# How to define column type in Spring/Hibernate when PSQL column type is character(2)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin

I have this Postgres `CREATE TABLE` statement

```
CREATE TABLE public.foo (
                                  id bigint NOT NULL,
                                  language character(2) NOT NULL,
                                  updated timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);
```

Now, this is how I try to define the column `language` in my `@Entity foo` in Kotlin

```
...
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column val language: AvailableLanguages,
...
```

`AvailableLanguages` is an `enum`

```
enum class AvailableLanguages {
    fr, en
}
```

However, this gives me the error

> ... org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [language] in table [foo]; found [bpchar (Types#CHAR)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]

I tried

```
@Column(length = 2)
```

which does not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you have some miss configuration.

To fix it you have to rewrite a bit your `sql` and that is all.

```
CREATE TABLE public.foo (
                                  id bigint NOT NULL,
                                  language varchar(2) NOT NULL,
                                  updated timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);
```

Because hibernate set default definition of column `String` in `varchar`, but if you want to change it you have to set `columnDefinition` parameter in `@Column` annotation.

Comment: what `columnDefinition` would I have to set?

Comment: I guess it should be `bpchar`

Comment: You also could change to `varchar` as I suggested in my answer